# Strategy For Font Family Availability

Tags: css, fonts

I'm looking for a strategy for dealing with font-family availability.

I have sites using OTFs  EOTs but for one reason or another, the font won't load for various devices/platforms and the font falls back to the 2nd or 3rd choice. Unfortunately, the fallback rarely has the same line-height or margins. I've used jQuery to adjust the CSS accordingly, but that's a lot of effort for anything but a very small style sheet. I'm wondering if there isn't a better strategy.

Or... if there's a way to troubleshoot -why- a Google Font or EOT or OTF won't load and perhaps cut down on those cases?

I realise one can use Google fonts and so on, but those are IMHO... forgive me... mostly -dreadful- looking.

Comment: You should specify some conditions under which font loading fails. The odds are that this is the constructive approach. Tuning line height an other properties for fallback fonts is close to being mission impossible.

Comment: The problem is that this will typically come from end users who aren't that great as informants. Perhaps there is a plug-in or some code advice available for trapping an error code/explanation when a font doesn't load?

Comment: Do you mean that downloadable fonts and CSS code for using them come from end users? If not, what then? If yes, what values you would set line height or margins to?

Comment: No. Eg. A random end user will call me from 1,000 miles away and say 'my site looks funny'. He e-mails me a screenshot and the issue is that the 'Ostrich' font did not load and the element is falling back to 'Arial'. I'd either like to know -why- (if there was a javascript function to catch this?) or have an easy way to match the actual height/characteristics of the fallback font. Thanks.

Comment: There are a few reasons why that might happen. The most common one is the lack of adequate font formats for different browsers. As long as you only mention OTF and EOT, this is probably the real problem. There are other reasons why loading may fail, but in lack of hard facts, like a URL, I would not want to speculate.

Answer (score 3):

Different browsers use different formats for fonts. For example, IE uses .eot files where as other browsers use .otf, .ttf, or even svg. Your best bet is to store multiple types of a font that would want to use and then declare them all in the @font-face block.

A good article about this can be found: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: Thanks. Good info. I well understand the different formats. I already deploy different versions. I didn't want to get too wordy. I'm more concerned about how to 'fall back' (if that's the right term) so that the 2nd choice font is the same size---with a minimum of effort. OR how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @jchwebdev, your question mentions OTF twice, with no hint to using other formats too.